# NPM Tunneling Socket Issues (Linux Redhat 6 and ATOM.io build)

Tags: linux, node.js, ssl, atom-editor

#Issue

I'm trying to build atom.io from scratch on redhat 6 behind a corporate firewall and I can't seem to make heads or tails of what is not working

#Thus far

There are various posts out there on these issues but none of them seem to help with my specific problem: (https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=npm+tunnel+socket).  I've spent a good time searching here and github for other "answers" and most of them cover adding some or all of the following configuration options>
The fixes offered include:

- a change to proxy settings
- stop doing strict ssl
- change the registry to http instead dog https
- And some random suggestion about **process.env.NODE_TLS...**

---

###NPM Settings

As you can see I've tried all these different settings (here is my npm configuration options) - although i'm unsure whether they are actually all working (see below)

```
; cli configs
user-agent = "npm/2.5.1 node/v0.12.0 linux x64"

; userconfig /home/jstein/.npmrc
http-proxy = "http://my-proxy:80"
https-proxy = "http://my-proxy:80/"
process.env.NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED = "0"
proxy = "http://my-proxy:80/"
registry = "http://registry.npmjs.org/"
strict-ssl = false

; node bin location = /devel/software/node-v0.12.0-linux-x64/bin/node
; cwd = /devel/software/atom
; HOME = /home/jstein
; 'npm config ls -l' to show all defaults.
```

---

##Error Condition

Even with these settings my build if failing in mysterious ways:

```
Node: v0.12.0
npm: v2.5.1
Installing build modules...
npm ERR! Linux 2.6.32-431.23.3.el6.x86_64
npm ERR! argv "/devel/software/node-v0.12.0-linux-x64/bin/node" "/devel/software/node-v0.12.0-linux-x64/    bin/    npm" "--userconfig=/devel/software/atom/.npmrc" "install" "--loglevel" "error"
npm ERR! node v0.12.0
npm ERR! npm  v2.5.1
npm ERR! code ECONNRESET

npm ERR! network tunneling socket could not be established, cause=connect EINVAL
npm ERR! network This is most likely not a problem with npm itself
npm ERR! network and is related to network connectivity.
npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
npm ERR! network
npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /devel/software/atom/build/npm-debug.log
```

###Logs

When I look at the build logs, however, i see something curious:

```
396 info attempt registry request try #1 at 10:20:13 AM
397 http request GET https://registry.npmjs.org/grunt-contrib-coffee
398 verbose request uri https://registry.npmjs.org/grunt-contrib-csslint
399 verbose request no auth needed
```

It appears that it is still trying to hit a **https** registry instead of listening to the command `registry = "http://registry.npmjs.org/"` so I'm wondering if that is part of the cause.

Also something else I'm unsure about is exactly how I can test this from command line.  Is there a way to do

`npm request get ....` or something like that?

###More Error

And just for the sake of completeness my failed build log ends with:

```
690 verbose stack Error: tunneling socket could not be established, cause=connect EINVAL
690 verbose stack     at ClientRequest.onError (/devel/software/node-v0.12.0-linux-x64/lib/node_modules/    npm/    node_modules/request/node_modules/tunnel-agent/index.js:168:17)
690 verbose stack     at ClientRequest.g (events.js:199:16)
690 verbose stack     at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:107:17)
690 verbose stack     at Socket.socketErrorListener (_http_client.js:272:9)
690 verbose stack     at Socket.emit (events.js:107:17)
690 verbose stack     at net.js:451:14
690 verbose stack     at process._tickCallback (node.js:355:11)
691 verbose cwd /devel/software/atom/build
692 error Linux 2.6.32-431.23.3.el6.x86_64
693 error argv "/devel/software/node-v0.12.0-linux-x64/bin/node" "/devel/software/node-v0.12.0-linux-x64/    bin    /npm" "--userconfig=/devel/software/atom/.npmrc" "install" "--loglevel" "error"
694 error node v0.12.0
695 error npm  v2.5.1
696 error code ECONNRESET
697 error network tunneling socket could not be established, cause=connect EINVAL
697 error network This is most likely not a problem with npm itself
697 error network and is related to network connectivity.
697 error network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
697 error network
697 error network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
697 error network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'
698 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

##Summary

I would like advice as to other steps I can take or a better way to figure out what is going on with these errors.  My work does use some sort of SSL Inspection which is probably breaking the https connection, however, I would think the configuration settings should inhibit this.

Thanks.

Comment: For version 2.14.7 I was able to do npm install , with a package.json, from behind a corporate proxy. To resolve error ".... cause=connect EINVAL.." I set the 'proxy' and 'https-proxy' in npm config. You need not set 'http-proxy'. If yours is a vagrant instance or a hosted VM setting proxy hostname might not work and you might want to use IP address.